# Why does this "next" not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get data through Ajax and fill them into div .content, but it won't work.

HTML:

```
<div class="review">
  <span class="seefull" rel="1">see full content</span>
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="c_createtime">(06-15 04:03:13)</div>
</div>

<div class="seg_r"><img src="http://img.dachaocai.com/sys/seg_2.gif"/></div>

<div class="review">
  <span class="seefull" rel="2">see full content</span>
  <div class="content">12</div>
  <div class="c_createtime">(07-31 12:46:18)</div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  $(".seefull").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/j/fullreview",
      data: {"t":"b","id":$(this).attr("rel")},
      success: function(data) {
        $(this).find("div .content").html(data);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: I think you're being so much brief. Can you explain in more detail what really happens? (Read console errors, warnings, etc..) ;)

Comment: there's no error or warning message, and i've already got data but they just wouldn't fill to the .content div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  $(function(){
        $(".seefull").click( function (){
            var $this = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:"/j/fullreview",
                data:{"t":"b","id":$this.attr("rel")},
                success:function(data){
                    $this.parent().find(".content").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
  });
```

It's about the context of "this".

When the ajax callback function executes, this does not refer to your original object anymore. So, you need to store its original reference on a variable, and use to that variable from there on to be sure you are always referring to the right element.

```
var $this = $(this);
```

With the above code, your object is now stored in the $this variable.

```
$this.parent().find(".content").html(data);
```

Find the parent of our element, then find the element with class "content", and change its content.

I didn't find a div of class content because from your code there is only one element with that class.

Comment: You are correct but it would be more helpful if you add an explanation.

Comment: @Felix yes, work in progress. Today I'm really slow and sloppy

Comment: Ok. I didn't say anything ;) :)

Comment: why changing '$this.parent().find(".content").html(data);' to '$this.next(".content").html(data);' won't work?

Comment: Check the jQuery docs for the [next method](http://api.jquery.com/next/). If $this is $(".seefull") like in my code, $this.next() will look for the next sibling of $('.seefull'), which is not obviously what you want. Additionally, $this.next('.content') will try to look for the next sibling of $('.seefull') with a class of content, which doesn't even exist.

Comment: "Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .next() method allows us to search through the immediately following sibling of **these elements**".

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is not working?

On first blush, I believe...

```
$(this).find("div .content").html(data);
```

should be...

```
$(this).parent().find("div.content").html(data);
```

And if `data` is a JSON object, then the output you will see will be something like `[Object] object` instead of any useful data, so additional parsing of the JSON object will be needed.

Comment: +1 there is an important difference between `div .content` and `div.content`.  The first is a div that contains something else with the class `content`, the second is a div **with** the class `content`

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I tried to remove the space and remove 'div', still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about the context...

```
 $(function(){
        $(".seefull").click(function(){
           vat that = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url:"/j/fullreview",
                data:{"t":"b","id":$(this).attr("rel")},
                success:function(data){
                    that.next().html(data);
                }
            })
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$(this).find("div .content").html(data);
```

to

```
$(this).parent().find("div.content").html(data);
```

**problem 1**:
`$(this)` refers to the span that was clicked, wich doesn't contain a div. use `parent()` to go ane level up in the dom-tree and search for `div.content` there.

**problem 2**:
`div .content` means "any element wich class *content* inside of a div".
this should be `div.content` wich means "a div with class *content*")

Comment: My fault, it was "next" in my code, i rewrote it when i ask this question. Why next won't work?